# Request for member 'resize' in Float64MultiArray which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, arduino, ros

I'm trying to compile a C++ Arduino sketch that uses the ROS data type [Float64MultiArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64MultiArray.html), and some [examples](http://answers.ros.org/question/232659/assign-c-array-to-ros-msg-array/?answer=232706#post-id-232706) say you're supposed to initialize it like:

```
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray array_msg;
array_msg.data.resize(9);
```

However, trying to compile my minimal sketch:

```
#include <std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h>

std_msgs::Float64MultiArray vec3_msg;

void setup() {
    vec3_msg.data.resize(3);
}

void loop() {
}
```

gives me the error:

```
main.ino: In function 'void setup()':
main.ino:6:19: error: request for member 'resize' in 'vec3_msg.std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::data', which is of non-class type 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::_data_type* {aka float*}'
     vec3_msg.data.resize(3);
                   ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example states:

> The message structure has a single field called data which can be
>   treated as a std::vector type in your C++ node.

But that does not apply to your case, since instead of using an underlying `std::vector`-like implementation, it defaulted to a plain `float` array, likely due to Arduino particularities (see [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial)).

You have to work with `vec3_msg.data` like with any other plain array. So:

```
vec3_msg.data = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    vec3_msg.data[i] = someValue;
}
```

is one way.

You probably want to keep a static array that you work with somewhere, and make your message's data point to it.

```
float myGlobalArray[9];

setup()
{
    vec3_msg.data = myGlobalArray;
}

// change myGlobalArray here and the
// data will update too.
```

Remember to set `vec3_msg.data_length` to 9 since in your case it's necessary. See [this answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160711134453/http://answers.ros.org/question/10988/use-multiarray-in-rosserial/) and the [MultiArrayLayout docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html) for extra info.

Comment: Spot on. None of the docs mentioned that the library switches implementations, but it makes perfect sense that it might do so.